# Gerrit clone very slow

Tags: git, github, clone, gerrit

I have 2 identical servers, one of them with GitHub Enterprise (2.2) and the other with Gerrit (2.11.3). When I try to clone a repository from GitHub machine, it takes about 15 minutes to clone it in parallel on 8 machines. Cloning same repository from Gerrit takes more than 3 hours just to count objects on remote side! On Github this step is almost instant... What have I done wrong? I have followed this steps: https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11.3/install.html to install Gerrit.

Comment: Why negative? I also encountered this problem, and I found the two steps "counting objects and finding sources" cost two much time. use garbage collection(ssh -p your_site gerrit gc --all) resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following page in order to get some tips how you can improve Gerrit performance:
https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/wiki/Scaling

I think you could start with adding some more memory.